# How do I set Cheetah 'useAutocalling' off?

Tags: google-app-engine, cheetah

I have tryed multiple ways to try and turn this off including

```
#compiler-settings
useAutocalling=False
#end compiler-settings

#compiler-settings
useAutocalling=0
#end compiler-settings
```

but I cannot get cheetah to turn it off. The reason I need to turn it off is because of a bug where google app engine's db.model has 'has_key' and it pisses off cheetah. I found the part in the documents about turning it off but no documentation on how to actually do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#compiler-settings
useAutocalling=False
useNameMapper=False
#end compiler-settings
```

thought to look though the source and find what it wanted and turns out i needed useNameMapper also turned off.